# Change the whole url in the address bar (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, address-bar

I need a code that changes the whole url in the address bar, (in javascript).
I have already searched upon this question all over the internet and found this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Page1" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1', 'Page1.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page2" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page2', 'Page2.htm');" />
<input type="button" value="Page3" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page3', 'Page3.htm');" />
```

But this doesn't changes the whole URL, it just changes

> localhost/index.php

to

> localhost/Page1.htm

Is there a way possible to change the whole URL? like from

> localhost.index.php

to

> Page1.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The History API does not let you change the apparent [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) of the page. That would be too useful for people making [Phishing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Phishing) attacks.

You can only change the path and what follows it.

Answer (score -1):

Use History.replaceState for your problem

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

Comment: `replaceState` is, like the `pushState` method used in the question, restricted to adjusting the path of the URL. It can't achieve the OP's desired goal.